# @angular/flex-layout 'space-between' layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, flexbox

I have 2 divs with images in them inside my ng2-flex-layout in my html template. I want 1 of those divs to be on the extreme left and the other on extreme right of the page.

My Code:

```
 <div class="flex-container" 
     fxLayout="row" 
     fxLayout.md="column"
     fxLayout.sm="column"
     fxLayout.xs="column"
     fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <div class="flex-item" fxLayoutAlign="left" fxFlex=50> <img></img></div>
  <div class="flex-item" fxFlex=50><img></img></div>
</div>
```

I am using     `"@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.4",`

I have tried  `layout-align="space-between center"` but no impact.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What result are you getting, and how does the container of this code look like?

Comment: I get an image on left and image in middle...in other words an image to the left of each div.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**First:** flex-layout requires Angular v2.4.3 or higher, make sure you meet that dependency.

**Second:** This code renders the result you are asking for. `fxLayout="row"` and `fxLayoutAlign="space-between center"` on your `flex-container` and then tagging your children with `flex-item` is all you need.

```
<div class="flex-container" 
    fxLayout="row" 
    fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <div class="flex-item"> 
    <img src="https://codepo8.github.io/canvas-images-and-pixels/img/horse.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://codepo8.github.io/canvas-images-and-pixels/img/horse.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Result:**
[image: result]

Comment: Thx. I'm not sure what i was doing incorrectly. That worked a treat